# Iterating an array in a foreach iteration of another array over all indexes

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, indexing, iteration

PHP. I have two MySQL tables. I want to make fieldsets and checkboxes. I don't know how to use indexes.

`buddies`, with each a `friend_id`. `assets`, with each an `asset_id`, an `asset_name`, and a `friend_id` referring to you know what.

I know how to get through one index. I don't know how to do the rest.

`print_r($buddies)` echoes:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [friend_id] => Peter ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [friend_id] => Stephanie ) )
```

`print_r($assets)` echoes

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [asset_id] => 39 [asset_name] => apple [friend_id] => Peter ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [asset_id] => 50 [asset_name] => pear [friend_id] => Peter ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [asset_id] => 51 [asset_name] => banana [friend_id] => Peter ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [asset_id] => 44 [asset_name] => apple [friend_id] => Stephanie ) ) )
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php 
 foreach ($buddies as $buddy) 
 {
     echo "<fieldset>";
     foreach ($assets as $asset)
     {
         if ($asset[0]->friend_id == $buddy->friend_id)
         {
             echo "<input value=\"".$asset[0]->asset_id."\">". $asset[0]->asset_name . "</input>";
         }
     }
     echo "</fieldset>";
 }
```

Comment: what's the original query, there probably should be a join in it

Comment: They are separate queries, one for each table, and just select from where, select from where. What type of join do you suggest for this, and in which direction?

Comment: Alright, left join did the trick. My second array was resulted from mysql using a left join, then I iterated it normally using an if statement to filter the asset for said buddy. Thanks, Dagon!